# how to know the user is paid to given upi id?

Tags: flutter, payment-gateway, qr-code, upi

I am developing a flutter app that uses UPI payment methods. but when I use packages like easyUPIpayment and any other upi package, I get payment failed. i researched in many way to solve this. but the solution is use a fully verified merchant account( solution is not tested by me). i don't want to use merchant payments in my app. so I decided to create a QR code that specifying the upi id and amount. the user only need to scan the upi id and pay. but i want to conform (not manually) the user has paid or not. how to do that? is ther any solution.
I found that use payment gateways is better solution for this. but payment gateways are charging money even for upi transactions. my app is for charity service so i need to avoid extra charges for collecting money. anyone has better solution for this?

i need better solution